# Create refocus effect for a image?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have got this image:
[image]
The idea is seperate the image to two using mask in U/V image editor, then blur each one to make it look like the camera changes its focus from the man to the ipod:
[image]

I've got the mask. But how I do that in node editor?

Blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it here. It's hard to do this in only blender. Using photoshop would simplify this..
    The idea is simple. Open photoshop (or GIMP whatever..) => load the image in => Cut it into two (Each one has a focal point, near and further) => Export them as PNG => Load the two images into Blender => Composite them, blur each one at a time to fake this defocusing effect!